# Cannot access properties of parent class from a type parameter that extends the class

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I have a decorator that adds some properties to a class and another decorator that needs that property added by the first one, like:

```
// this class adds the type support
abstract class TypeDefClass {
  readonly p!: number;
}

type Newable<T = any> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

const addProperties = <T extends Newable<TypeDefClass>>(target: T) => {
  return class extends target {
    p: number = 0;
  }
}

const readProperty = <T extends Newable<TypeDefClass>>(target: T) => {
  // use the target.p property
  target.p // property p does not exist on T, but it should right?
}
```

however if I do

```
// though this will not applicable to a class, since it's not newable
// and will result in a type mismatch
const readProperty = (target: TypedefClass) => {
  target.p; // its fine
}
```

I doubt my definition of type `Newable` is incorrect, and I don't know which definition of `readProperty` is correct. I am fairly new to decorators, any help is much appreciated.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQMYBsCGt4oCaflAphAJ4AOBsArscQPYBO4AUCgEazi0oLiKrqgAqJPABE8AMwDCveAG8GoULTxZqAOySFQxAIQAuUKvIBbZnloBuBgF8GDcENAA5PAHcWSPAB5%20oALygUVUIAPj8DV1AACgA6WJRaAHNYfUDCAG0AXQBKP1D%20SwYENTYA7AAFWmpSemg8eH9vUDwAD3A8VRwnV3cvQVJRSWlg4MjweIS8cH1%20HN9QuQUlcHJaVR40eBa2jtxxydAFhS19QxMzMIAGSwUbG0Li7iUsCqqzezDGrfbO5zdmD28QgGUg2w1GeymAlm83koBAoHIsAI%20AgEOixC0lWq9lhY0Sk3RcLAxCxb00GMw1DqBmo3BacG4agEABpQMxyNxoNxYJBqOQkJhFNAEpBwAB%20ay2AACT0wL2xhAYUqwctJNTqhWkoAAGk1Wt94H0ROIQXw5NYgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because you didn't instantiate the class.

When I pulled in your code I:

1: Noticed you spelled TypedefClass wrong ;) It should be TypeDefClass as per your definition :)
2: Was able to access the `p` property *after* `target` was instantiated.

If you want to access it statically, perhaps declare `p` to be static?

Comment: hey, yeah I corrected that typo. But I can't really instantiate the class since I am using inversify. And property `p` is object specific so can't really declare it static

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, we can't really access an instance property from the type itself. I realize now that I'm asking the wrong question.